# Create a hyperlink to a sheet with same name as the value in the selected cell in Excel through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the code to first check if a single cell is selected in the sheet I am in, and then check if a sheet exists in the Workbook with the same value as the value in the selected cell.

If these conditions are met, I am trying to creates a hyperlink in the selected cell which points to the sheet with the same name/value.

For example, if I select a cell (A1) that has the value "1000" in it, and there is a sheet named "1000", I want the code to create a hyperlink  in cell A1 to the sheet named "1000".

I tried the following code and it gives me "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument on this line of code;

selectedCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=selectedCell, Address:="", SubAddress:=selectedCell.Value & "!", TextToDisplay:=selectedCell.Value

```
Sub CreateHyperlinkToSheet()
    Dim selectedCell As Range
    Set selectedCell = Selection

    If selectedCell.Count <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a single cell.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not SheetExists(selectedCell.Value) Then
        MsgBox "No sheet exists with the name '" & selectedCell.Value & "'.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    selectedCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=selectedCell, Address:="", SubAddress:=selectedCell.Value & "!", TextToDisplay:=selectedCell.Value
End Sub

Function SheetExists(sheetName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = (Len(Sheets(sheetName).Name) > 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: `selectedCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=selectedCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & selectedCell.Value & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=selectedCell.Value`

Comment: Tried replacing with your code, unfortunately got the same error message.

Comment: I edited my comment (as I had omitted the final 'e' from `.Value` at the end) - the syntax as it currently stands is valid syntax

Comment: Still getting the same error message, and the debugger points me to this line of code.

Comment: `selectedCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=selectedCell, Address:="#'" & selectedCell.Value & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="" & selectedCell.Value & ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Spectral Instance who found the solution and wrote it in the comments;

```
selectedCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=selectedCell, Address:="#'" & selectedCell.Value & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="" & selectedCell.Value & ""
```

The error message was due to the value of the cell beeing a number. In this case the cell A1 had the value of 1000.